# How do I format json data with ruby on rails helpers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-3.2, handlebars.js

I've spent the last few days reading up on and familiarising myself with handlebars.js templating and it's great.

Right now I'm working with one of my partials that has a bunch of html where I have used helpers such as simple_format, time_ago_in_words and so on. Obviously these helpers can't be used with handlebars. So I'd like to do something like this:

```
def get_micropost

   respond_to do |format|   
     format.json { render json: formatted_micropost_json_data(Micropost.where("id < ?", params[:micropost_id]).first) } 
   end

end
```

**Microposts helper:**

```
module MicropostsHelper

    def formatted_micropost_json_data(micropost)

        content: simple_format h(micropost.content)
        created_at: time_ago_in_words(micropost.created_at)
        id: micropost.id
        image: micropost.image
        link: micropost.link
        poster_id: micropost.poster_id
        updated_at: micropost.updated_at 
        user_id: micropost.user_id 

    end

end
```

So when I get the JSON back via an ajax call it will already be formatted correctly. Then I can simple just display my handlebars variables as normal.

Would this even work?

If not what would be the best way to do this?

Kind regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's my suggested rewrite of your code:

```
class Micropost
  def formatted_json_data
    {
      content:    simple_format(h(self.content)),
      created_at: time_ago_in_words(self.created_at),
      id:         self.id,
      image:      self.image,
      link:       self.link,
      poster_id:  self.poster_id,
      updated_at: self.updated_at,
      user_id:    self.user_id
    }
  end
end

def get_micropost
  respond_to do |format|   
    format.json do
      posts = Micropost.where("id < ?", params[:micropost_id])
      data = posts.first.formatted_json_data
      render(json: data)
    end
  end
end
```

You wanted to your a hash literal inside your method - what you had originally was not syntactically-valid ruby code.

Also breaking up the long line of chained method calls might make for more informative error messages and provide clearer opportunities to handle them.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I have missed commas. In any case, your approach for current problem is better and much scalable.

Comment: I'm getting Status Code:500 Internal Server Error when using ajax to get the get_microposts url. This didn't happen before.. Not too sure why it's happening now.

Comment: Well I'm not sure what the rest of your code looks like, so you'll have to adapt my answer sensibly to work with the rest of it. The 500 error probably indicates a ruby error has been raised - if you could inspect the logs to find the name and backtrace of the error then that might shed some more light on it.

Comment: This is the error: NoMethodError (undefined method `formatted_json_data' for #<Micropost:0x0000010525b830>):

Comment: Did you define the method like I did? I put it as an instance method of the model because that seemed sensible to me. I'm not sure how `h` and `time_ago_in_words` are scoped, so if it's more practical to keep it as a helper like you had it then fine, but the important part was to fix the hash literal syntax by adding curly braces and commas like I did.

Comment: This led me to my answer. Thanks